# Nhibernate Subquery - Could not resolve property of type x

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

I need some help figuring out a query which should filter based on one to many relationship. I have a tables 'Product' and 'ProductType'. Where 'Product' has many 'ProductType'. These models are working great I just can't figure out how to filter 'Product' records based on 'ProductType' records.

In this example I would like to select all a 'Product' where Product.Name == "somename" && Product.Version == "9.6". I want to filter these results where ProductType.Type == "someType".
The following is throwing an exception:

> could not resolve property: ProductType of: my.namespace.ProductType

I am using examples from Ayende's blog: [Query Examples](http://ayende.com/blog/4023/nhibernate-queries-examples)

```
 var product = _session.CreateCriteria<Product>()
                              .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Name", "somename"))
                              .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Version", "9.6"))
                              .Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("Id",
                                                         DetachedCriteria.For<ProductType>()
                                                                         .SetProjection(Projections.Property("Product.Id"))
                                                                         .CreateCriteria("ProductType")
                                                                         .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Type", "someType"))
                                       )).List<Product>().SingleOrDefault();
```

Am I close? Can someone offer me some help? Thanks!

**Edit**

This has me close. If I remove the second CreateCriteria I get back a product that has the Types populated. As soon as I add the join back.. I get 0 results.

```
 var products = _session.CreateCriteria("Product")
                                   .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Name", "somename"))
                                   .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Version", "9.6")) //This works
                                   .CreateCriteria("Types", "productTypes",   JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
                                   .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Type", "typename")).List<Product>();

            return products.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Very close - you just need to tell CreateCriteria how to get to ProductType. For example:

```
var product = _session.CreateCriteria<Product>()
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Name", "somename"))
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Version", "9.6"))
    .Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("Id",
         DetachedCriteria.For<ProductType>()
        .SetProjection(Projections.Property("Product.Id"))
        .CreateCriteria("Product.ProductType", JoinType.InnerJoin)
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Type", "someType"))
     ))
     .List<Product>()
     .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: That's weird I get the same issue.

Comment: Actually.. now it complains could not resolve property: Product.Id of:{namespace}

Comment: Could you update the question with the Product and ProductType classes, as well as the mappings you've used?